# Can we create ‘Native Ads’ in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, hybrid-mobile-app, native-ads

I want to implement the native Ads in the ionic app. I have seen some native android apps which are using Native Ads to display Ads in the middle of the app content. I need the same functionality to display Ads in specific position of the app. Currently I am using google admob plugin for ads, I am able to create banner Ads and interstitial Ads but I need Ads in middle of content of the app.

is there any way to implement native ads in ionic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Guys, I found solution for this, it may helps some others.

Comment: Hi Harish, Can you please tell us what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ionic with google admob we can't create 'Native ads'

we have used 'Facebook audience network' ads for integrating the native ads in ionic.

we have a clear cordova plugin to integrate facebook ads which make my work simpler.

you can refer this cordova plugin : https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads

if any one has any issue with this plugin integration you can post here, i will try to help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the code? Especially the part where you link the clickable area and update the clickable area once the user starts scrolling the page.

If you have the code in TypeScript, that would be great. I'm using Ionic 2.

Comment: Hi Sathish, we have added a directive to detect scroll change event so from that directive we are making a call to update click add position(click area) From that directive, I  am making a call to 'setNativeAdClickArea' method of the plugin and passing AdID, x-axis position and y-axis position and add height and width.

Comment: I implemented it in my 'Ionic 2' application few weeks back and have released the app ..I've made the code public on my blog [Facebook Native Ads Clickable Area: Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5151/facebook-native-ads-clickable-area-ionic-2/), so that others in same situation are being helped with the actual code.

Anyway thank you for letting me know how you implemented it.

Comment: Alright thanks, looks good @Harishs! out of curiousity, how has it been so far? The fillrate,ecpm,cpm etc been fine?

Comment: How to get deviceHash for testing on cordova based projects?

Answer (score 8):

As most people have replied, the answer is still a **NO**. You can't yet implement AdMob's Native Ad in Ionic.

The other alternative though is, **Facebooks Audience Network**. I spent some days figuring out how to make it work in an '**Ionic 2**' application. I've made the code public on my blog along with Video Tutorials to implement the same. Hope it'll be helpful for some of you.

**1.** [Facebook Native Ads: Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5128/facebook-native-ads-ionic-2/)

**2.** [Facebook Native Ads Clickable Area: Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5151/facebook-native-ads-clickable-area-ionic-2/)

Other codes ..(just in case someone is still looking for it)

**3.** [Facebook Banner and Interstitial Ads: Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5123/facebook-banner-and-interstitial-ads-ionic-2/)

**4.** [Adding AdMob In Ionic 2](http://technotip.com/5113/adding-admob-in-ionic-2/) (Banner, Interstitial and Rewarded Video Ads.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the answer is "no". ionic/Cordova based on a webview. Native ad requires to be displayed in a native view, and you can not insert a native view to a webview.
There are still two options that I will not recommend to use:

1. Use a plug in called "Cordova admob pro" along with Facebook audience network. It is using a "hack" way to display facebook native ad: display ad content in webview, and a clickable transparent-background native view in front of the webview, using bridge codes to let the native view to cover the webview-ad. I do not recommend this because it is too complicated and you can not implement it "freely".
2. Many ad networks provide Mobile Web API. They are all javascript API, so you can easily insert ads to your content. But this kind of usage is not listed in any of their documents. So it is a risk.

I'd recommend you to take a look at "react native" + facebook audience network.

Comment: Thank you Stan hou

Comment: Can we make changes in facebookad plugin to show Advance Native Ad?
If yes Then Can you @Stan Hou please elaborate what are the steps?