# Providing Native Ads within a Cordova/Ionic 4 Mobile application?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, facebook-audience-network

I want to be able to implement native ads (Custom Ads to fit within my mobile app and **not** banner/interstitial ads) within my ionic app. Are there any existing cordova plugins that can be used to achieve this?

There are some questions related to this asked several years ago ([Can we create ‘Native Ads’ in ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821764/can-we-create-native-ads-in-ionic)) ([Native Admob ads using ionic/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063960/native-admob-ads-using-ionic-cordova)) which the answers result in a no but wondering if this has changed over the years

I am also concerned with some ad related plugins that currently exist for Cordova/Ionic as there have been some reports which developers have complained about revenue lost/stolen from maintainers (https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/354) (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/issues/698)

The closest solution to what I want to achieve seems to be implementing Admob Pro (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) and using a mediation to the Facebook Audience Network to provide a "hack" implementation with very little flexibility. However, I can face the concern of potential lost/stolen revenue with this path by using this plugin.

Any solutions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think if there isn't a solution to this then I will need to resort to using an Admob free plugin and displaying banners ads instead which really isn't ideal but that might be the only solution that exists in the meantime

Comment: Ya, So meanwhile there is no way to integrate native ads with Ionic right?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the meantime

Comment: I was able to use Google AdSense ads within my AngularJS based cordova app by loading the SDK in an iframe via the app's website. It worked for a while but it's not working anymore. Will have to check what went wrong, but just wanted to share the idea for anyone who may still be looking.